# How can I insert the symbols into the caption of a figure?

Tags: captions

I am having plots in my text. In the plots, the data sets are represented by different symbols. I'd like to explain data sets by using the symbols in the caption of the figure too. How can I insert that symbols into te caption ?

for example:

[image: Caption of a Figure]

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have any idea how to solve this problem and I don't even know what the \protect is for

Comment: I'd recommend (a) keeping the caption short and (b) putting the `This work: ... [blue open pentagon].` material into a legend.

Comment: I think the Mico's recomendation is the best idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the symbols you need in [symbols-a4.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). You can change their colour using the [color](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/color) package or the [xcolor](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1.0,0.4,0.0}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering\rule{4cm}{4cm} %Replace with image.
\caption{\textcolor{blue}{$\medsquare$}
         \textcolor{orange}{$\medtriangleup$}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It might take some effort to get all the colours and sizes exactly right, though.

Comment: wow thanks, I didn't expect the solution will be that difficult.